# Cannot save Mosaico Templates

Tags: civimail, mosaico

We are on the latest version of civicrm 5.3.1 and the lastest version of Masaico and now i am getting this error message when I try to edit and save a template:

> API permission check failed for MosaicoTemplate/create call;
>   insufficient permission: require edit message templates and edit
>   user-driven message templates and edit system workflow message
>   templates

Thanks Karin!

Answer (score 3):

There are some new permisssions to review/set: navigate to your where set permissions in your CMS. In Drupal: People -> Permissions - and look for these:

[image]